# Excel Addin and Excel Interopt

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Ok I am creating an Excel Addin almost like the one from TFS
It retrieves information
Then when changes needs to be saved.

I succeeded in all of that but I have a flickering Issue with excel.
As it loads the information from the server and then writes to cells in excel its like the mouse is flickering and each row is filled cell by cell very very slowly

But with TFS when you retrieve all tasks it is like one shot and its there in excel, no flickering.

How can this be achieved ?

Here is how I add the data into Excel

```
//Get the table (Index never changes and the addin checks an "VeryHiden" Contentsheet for compatibility)
var tableRetainer = _workingsheet.ListObjects[2];
for(var rowRetainer = 1; rowRetainer++;
{
 //get the specific devision from the List<Dictionary<string,object>>
 rangeRetainer[rowRetainer, 1].Value2 = devision["FeeAgreementID"];
 rangeRetainer[rowRetainer, 2].Value2 = devision["Task"];
 rangeRetainer[rowRetainer, 3].Value2 = devision["Tariff"];
 rangeRetainer[rowRetainer, 4].Value2 = devision["Quantity"];
}
```

Comment: Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before your code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` afterwards

Comment: Thanks to that, and also Taosique's answer I managed to understand Interopt more than I did, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you write to each cell individually? If yes, try optimizing by pasting large ranges at once. Anyway, you should try to make as few calls through Interop boundary as possible.

Plus you might consider alternatives like writing via ACE OleDB if you don't care about formatting.

Comment: The Excel Addin Connects via sockets to the server, the server then sends back a List<Dictionary<string,object>>, with that I write it to each cell. I have created a a Template excel file with a table then I access that table and fill each row using a foor-loop and then by accessing each cell and set the value

Comment: You can use `Range.set_Value(Missing.Value, MyArrayOfValues[,])` to paste an array of values at once.

Comment: Really ? wow thats cool, one last question on this.
I propably need to Include the table Column Headers inside MyArrayOfValues[,] because I am doing this

    var tableRetainer = _workingsheet.ListObjects[2];
    var rangeRetainer = tableRetainer.Range;

But now with rangeRetainer Row 1 is the header